# Displaying the amount of memory allocated

Tags: c, windows, memory-management

Hi
I'm writing some test stuff to see the amount of memory that allocated displayed correctly

in Windows TasK manager. Below is the code;

```
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
 struct stat st;
 char commandXCopy[200];
 char commandDelete[200];

 char *fNames[2^16];
 int i =0;
    char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2^32);
     printf("\nTEST");

    if(!ptr)
            printf("\nCan not allocate");
    else
            printf("\nMemory allocate");


     while(1==1)
     {
     };
```

I try to make huge allocations from stack and heap. But all I see on task manager->processes is ~800K.

And I don't see "Can not allocate" message either.

I have Windows 32bit XP Pro and use gcc and application is a dos application.

> gcc test.c

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may be suffering under a misapprehension: `2^32` is *not* 2<sup>32</sup> (4G, assuming your bytes are eight bits long, which I will for the purposes of this answer) in C.

`^` is the bitwise XOR operator. So what you're actually allocating is:

```
     binary        hex     decimal
    ---------      ----    -------
    0010 0000      0x20      32
xor 0000 0010      0x02       2
    =========
    0010 0010      0x22      34
```

or 34 bytes. Similarly, `2^31` would give you 29 bytes so what you may think should be a 2G difference (2<sup>32</sup> - 2<sup>31</sup>) is really only 5 bytes.

If you want to do powers in C, you should look at the `pow()` function but I doubt you'll be able to get 4G of memory (perhaps on a 64-bit OS but even then, that's an awful lot).

And just one other thing: `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1 - there's no need to multiply by it.

Comment: On the other hand..When I changed code to this                                                                                                                                     char *ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) *pow(2,30));                                                          i still have 840K in task manager.Why?

Comment: I'll near-guarantee it's because the allocation actually _failed_, and failed allocations don't tend to take up much of your address space :-) Check ptr after the malloc to see if it's NULL.

Comment: No,allocation is successful. I check ptr against null and see the message "Memory allocate"

Comment: Then I'd be looking into what the figures actually mean in task manager. The processes tab may not be useful: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager : "1/ The Mem Usage column on the Processes tab is actually the process' working set. The process has little or no direct control over its working set, which turns this column useless to determine how much memory a process is consuming" and "2/ The VM Size column (not shown by default) is not the amount of virtual memory used by the process; it is actually the process' private bytes".

Comment: You may be better off looking into WMI to get the information you need.

Comment: I downloaded Process Explorer and now can see memory usage of application. It's called Private Bytes and a member of working set.

Comment: As you said task manager misleads , one should use different tools for asking how much memory is allocated in his application